# what is the logic for paragraph validation in multiline Textbox using javascript?

Tags: javascript

i am trying to validate text(Paragraph) in javascript for multiline Textbox. 
After giving the text in textbox, the very first Letter should be changed to Capital letter, remaining have to remain as small letters.After full stop the first letter should be in Capital. I need to use textchange event also.

I am new to javascript, and i feel this Proper Case validation is very complex, i am not even getting any logic to start with.. Plz give some idea.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You probably want to do this with regular expressions. I can write you a sample one, but first, are you sure this validation makes sense? there are often good reasons to have capital letters in the middle of a sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a possible answer, though to reiterate my comment, I don't actually think this is a very useful validation approach. You can see a working version here: http://jsfiddle.net/nrabinowitz/5TSK5/

```
// regex for a single sentence
var testRE = /^[A-Z][^A-Z]+$/;

var paragraphs = text.split('\n');

var pass, paragraph, sentences, sentence;
for (var x=0; x < paragraphs.length; x++) {
    paragraph = paragraphs[x];
    pass = true;
    if (paragraph) {
        sentences = paragraph.split(/\. +/);
        for (var y=0; y < sentences.length; y++) {
            sentence = sentences[y];
            // test sentence for validity
            if (sentence && !testRE.exec(sentence)) {
                pass = false;  
            }
        }
        // pass is now either true or false for paragraph x
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look for a plugin that already does grammar checking like [After The Deadline](http://www.afterthedeadline.com/).

@nrabinowitz is right, I wouldn't try to write a natural language grammar checker in javascript unless your stated goal of "capitalization should only occur after a full stop" is the full extent of what you want to do, you'd be attempting to parse a potentially non-context-free language.

Comment: What actually i have to do is Capitalization should occur in the very first letter and also after the full stop. This all has to happen automatically when i enter text in textbox.. regular expression will work or i ve to try some thing else??